# [React, Ant Design]- Tree - How to only select parent, not selet child

Tags: reactjs, tree, antd

I have a problem when I select parent, the tree will default to select all children, I want to select parent will not select child, when I select child, it will select

Hope to get support
Thank all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Đỗ Duy Đoàn Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `checkStrictly={true}` property, in your Tree component :

```
 <Tree
  checkable={true}
  checkStrictly={true}
  onCheck={onCheck}
  treeData={treeData}
/>
```

See [Ant Design documentation](https://ant.design/components/tree).